# Display compile errors for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I used to start React normally like it is advised in their tutorial, and in this context it displays compile errors.

Now, I've set up a **webpack config** for a React project and when it doesn't compile there is just a blank page.

Is there a way to display these errors on terminal or on the browser page ?

Thank you for your answers

**EDIT :**

[image]

```
    var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'/Users/Martin/Documents/Projets_Web/API-CJ/build',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Webpack does display compile errors in the terminal. Can you screenshot your terminal after compilation? Most likely it's a problem with your configuration.

Comment: I've edited my post according to your answer

Comment: Please, post your full webpack config file.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Everything seems alright. What are you trying to render? Maybe the component is empty, or the id's do not match, or...

Comment: To be honest I'm not facing a problem yet but I feel disappointed about this situation. I surely would need this "debugger" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the level of stats webpack output to the terminal passing a stats settings object. Here is the relevant part of my server app (node+express+webpack dev)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  // dynamically require webpack dependencies
  // to them in devDependencies (package.json)
  const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack/development.webpack.config')
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
  const webpack = require('webpack')

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: webpackConfig.stats,
    progress: true,
    hot: true
  }))

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

} else {

  // compression middleware compresses your server responses
  // which makes them smaller (applies also to assets).
  // You can read more about that technique and other good
  // practices on official Express.js docs http://mxs.is/googmy
  app.use(compression())

  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './dist')))
}
```

In my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {

  devtool: 'source-map',

  context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),

  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      path.resolve('./src/client/index.js')
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  stats: {
    // Add asset Information
    assets: true,
    // Sort assets by a field
    assetsSort: "field",
    // Add information about cached (not built) modules
    cached: true,
    // Add children information
    children: true,
    // Add chunk information (setting this to `false` allows for a less verbose output)
    chunks: false,
    // Add built modules information to chunk information
    chunkModules: true,
    // Add the origins of chunks and chunk merging info
    chunkOrigins: false,
    // Sort the chunks by a field
    chunksSort: "field",
    // Context directory for request shortening
    context: "../src/",
    // `webpack --colors` equivalent
    colors: true,
    // Add errors
    errors: true,
    // Add details to errors (like resolving log)
    errorDetails: true,
    // Add the hash of the compilation
    hash: false,
    // Add built modules information
    modules: false,
    // Sort the modules by a field
    modulesSort: "field",
    // Add public path information
    publicPath: false,
    // Add information about the reasons why modules are included
    reasons: false,
    // Add the source code of modules
    source: false,
    // Add timing information
    timings: true,
    // Add webpack version information
    version: true,
    // Add warnings
    warnings: false
  },

  // ... rest of config ...
```

For a production build, I'm using this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

function webpackCompiler (webpackConfig) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const compiler = webpack (webpackConfig)

    compiler.run((err, stats) => {

      if (err) {

        console.log('Webpack compiler encountered a fatal error.', err)
        return reject(err)
      }

      const jsonStats = stats.toJson()

      console.log(stats.toString(webpackConfig.stats))

      resolve(jsonStats)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = webpackCompiler
```